# An irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb R[x,y]$, whose zero set in $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^2$ is not irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise on Page 8 of Hartshone's *Algebraic Geometry*:

> Give an example of an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb R[x,y]$, whose zero set $Z(f)$ in $\mathbb A_{\mathbb R}^2$ is not irreducible.

I think such an example must come from the fact that $\mathbb R$ is not algebraically closed. But I have no idea as to finding a concrete one.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is the empty set reducible?

Comment: Very similar to Mariano's example is the polynomial $f(x, y) = y^2 + x^2 (x - 1)^2$ given in Exercise 1.26 in William Fulton's Algebraic Curves book.

Comment: Dear @ PseudoNeo, no the empty set is explicitly said to be  *non* irreducible in EGA  and De Jong's Stack Project, as well as in many other sources.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: As I wrote “reducible”, I guess your “no” is a “yes“? One of those days, I'll write a linguistics thesis on the mathematicians' jargon. A language where “non irreducible” or “isn't nondegenerate” are common phrases clearly deserves more attention.

Comment: Dear @Pseudoneo, you are quite right: my "no" is a "yes" and it *is* strange that one says that the empty set is not irreducible rather than reducible! In the same vein algebraic geometers used to say that a variety was nonsingular (and even not nonsingular to emphasize that a singularity was present!) but fortunately Zariski coined the word regular to replace nonsingular in his magnificent creation of a purely algebraic definition for the concept. And if you ever write that linguistics thesis, I'd love to see  a  copy :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I don't know about this particular use, but conceivably the empty set is considered not irreducible but not reducible either. I'm pretty certain that in a UFD (or integral domain) the invertible elements (and zero) are considered to be neither irredicible nor composite, which is not too different a situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$f(x,y)=(x^2-1)^ 2+y^2$ works, as far as I can tell.

To show this is irreducible: if $f$ is a product of two non-constant factors $g$ and $h$, the product of the leading forms of $g$ and $h$ is $x^4$. We can assume then that these leading forms are either $x$ and $x^3$ or $x^2$ and $x^2$. In the first case, one of the factors is linear and this is  impossible because it would have infinitely many zeroes, and $f$ does not. The factors must then both have $x^2$ as initial form, and $g$ is then of the form $x^2+ax+by+c$ with $a$, $b$ and $c$ reals. If $b$ is not zero, this has infinitely many zeroes and so then so has $f$: we know this is not true; it follows that $g$ depends only on $x$; the same works for $h$. This is absurd.

Comment: Dear Mariano, wouldn't it be simpler to notice that $f$ seen as a polynomial in $y$ has no root in $\mathbb R[x]$, because the sum of two  squares (not both zero) in $\mathbb R[x]$ is non zero ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, sure it is! I have spent too much time recently thinking about the shape of polynomials :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. As to the the proof of the irreducibility of $f$, can I do it like this? Firts, factor $f$ as $f=f_1f_2$ in $\mathbb C[x,y]$ where $f_1=(x-1)+iy,f_2=(x-1)-iy$. Clearly both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are irreducible and none of them is in $\mathbb R[x,y]$. Then conclude that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[x,y]$. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I am pretty curious about how did you come up with this example? Could you tell me about that?

Answer (score 4):

**Added**: This answer interprets "irreducible" to mean with respect to the classical (analytic) topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$, not the (relative) Zariski topology.

Consider the **elliptic curve** $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$\Delta = 4A^3 + 27B^2 \neq 0$.

Then the polynomial $f(x,y) = x^3 + Ax + B - y^2$ is irreducible.  However the real zero set of $f$ has two components iff $x^3 + Ax + B$ has three real roots (see e.g. [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aECClines-3.svg) for a good idea of what's going on here).  Thus taking for instance $A = -1, B = 0$ gives an answer to the question.

If you want to think about things this way, a natural followup result is **Harnack's Theorem**: if $C/\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth, geometrically integral projective curve of genus $g$, then the real locus $C(\mathbb{R})$ has at most $g+1$ connected (hence irreducible, by smoothness) components, and all numbers of components between $0$ and $g+1$ are possible.  Thus the above example is in some sense the simplest.

Comment: Why is this curve not connected for the Zariski topology ? Doesn't Harnack theorem involves transcandental topology ?

Comment: @user10676: thanks, you're absolutely correct.  I added a warning to this effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and the deeper insight.